# KNN based on distance instead of neighbours

Tags: python, knn

I have three columns and I need to find near by values like below

```
A            B        Distance

point_a    point_b      20

point_a    point_c      30

point_a    point_d      40

point_a    point_e      25

point_g    point_a      26


point_c    point_d      30

point_c    point_e      30


point_d    point_e      40
```

I need to find all the near by points

For ex -  If I want to find all near by points from point_a within 28 miles  it will be point_b, point e and point g

Comment: So you can go through your database, find all rows that contains `point_a`, wether it is the first or the second element, and store minimum `k` points.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for example a simple `pandas` query and don't need any machine learning algorithm:

```
result = df.query("(A == 'point_a' | B == 'point_a') & Distance < 28")
```

or

```
result = df[((df['A'] == 'point_a') | (df['B'] == 'point_a')) & (df['Distance'] < 28)]
```

Result:

```
         A        B  Distance
0  point_a  point_b        20
3  point_a  point_e        25
4  point_g  point_a        26
```

Get a set of nearest points:

```
result = result[['A', 'B']].stack().unique().tolist()
result = set(result)
result.remove('point_a')
```

Result:

```
{'point_e', 'point_g', 'point_b'}
```